# Cannot convert Array into String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm having trouble with this code (again).
I'm trying to get Ruby to check if `tree` is equal to any of the items in `$do_not_scan` and all I'm getting is a "`cannot convert Array into String`" error. Any way to fix such a thing?

My code:

```
#filesniffer by Touka, ©2015
$filecount = 0
$trees = Dir.entries("C:\\")
$do_not_scan = ["bootmgr", "BOOTNXT", "USER", ".", "Documents and Settings", "PerfLogs", "System Recovery", "System Volume Information", "$RECYCLE.BIN"]
def scan
    $trees.each do |tree|
        unless tree.include?($do_not_scan[0...8])
            puts "scanning #{tree}"
            entries = Dir.entries("c:\\#{tree}")
            entries.each do |filename|
                if filename == "**\*.dll"
                    puts "Found #{filename} in #{tree}"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
def scan_loop
    $trees.each do |tree|
        scan
        unless tree.include?($do_not_scan[0...8])
            subtrees = Dir.entries("#{tree}")
            subtrees.each do |tree|
                scan
                scan_loop
            end
        end
    end
end
scan_loop
sleep
```

Comment: I would use a Regexp instead. It would help me avoid the issue of case-sensitive comparison of folder names. Also, I would avoid recursion, it uses more resources and there is no need for it in this case.

Comment: you are also calling scan without updating `$trees`. You could get rid of the global variable `$trees` all together by passing it as an argument to the `#scan` and `#scan_loop` methods

Comment: side note - please stop using `$global` variables.   They just aren't used in ruby.     Normal variables do not need a `$`

Comment: "They just aren't used in ruby." Yes they are, just not very often in normal code and they're a hint that someone doesn't know what they're doing if overused/abused, as in this case. In this case they're an indicator that the OP doesn't understand variable scoping.

Comment: Why try to reinvent a very well tested and prewritten wheel? Ruby comes with the [Find](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class that will do a recursive descent of a directory hierarchy. Use it instead of trying to do it yourself. Or investigate using [`Dir.glob('**/*.dll')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) as it's an alternate path.

Comment: Just so you know -- in line 11 the backslash does not appear in the resulting string, it's just `"***.dll"` (either use single quotes or double backslash). Also, `scan` and `scan_loop` do almost the same and can be factored out. Also, you can get rid of `.each ... unless` via [`Enumerable#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) available on Arrays too. Also, I believe `Dir[File.join('**', '*.dll')]` does pretty much the same only that it's much shorter and is without a blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following have to change in the `scan` and `scan_loop` methods:

```
$do_not_scan[0...8].include?(tree)
```

In place off:

```
tree.include?($do_not_scan[0...8])
```

Comment: it's a step in the right direction but it's trying to scan files now. (need to head to class so I'll check back later)